# Calling function from outside the class in python or from another file

Tags: python, inheritance, selenium-webdriver

In the below code how can I call function `open_url()` from outside the class or from another file in python ?

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re
from selenium import webdriver

seed_url="http://www.google.com"
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://www.google.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_urlfunctions(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel = webdriver.Firefox()

        def open_url(url):
            sel.get(url)

        open_url(seed_url)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, were this a "normal" class and a "normal" method, you could instantiate the object, and simply call it.

i.e.

```
foo = Test()
foo.open_url()
```

However, this class is not intended to be used that way, as it would only have a default constructor which, while it would create an instance of the object, would be essentially empty, although I suppose you could explicitly call the other functions yourself.

Rather, this class appears like it's meant to be used by a test framework (perhaps *nose*), which will automatically call the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods when appropriate, and then automatically run the test methods.

Further, this particular method, `open_url`, if your indentation is correct, is scoped to the `test_urlfunctions` function, and so you couldn't call it from outside the class, unless you were to go through some contortions such as having the `test_urlfunctions` method return the function which could then be used elsewhere. However, that would defeat the point of having it scoped locally and having this setup to be used with a test framework.

For example, here's a smaller example of this. Given this code:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print "in bar"

        def inner_bar():
            print "in inner_bar"

        inner_bar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar()
    foo.inner_bar()
```

This results in the following output:

> ```
> in bar
> in inner_bar
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "so_class.py", line 14, in <module>
>     foo.inner_bar()
> AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'inner_bar'
> ```

This shows that `inner_bar()` can't be called via the object itself from the outside as-is.

What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to do this here?

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

If you want to run *Selenium* outside of the context of a test framework, you could decouple it from that by not inheriting from `unittest` and reshuffling the functions and how you call them (since they would no longer be automatically called by the test framework).

However, you say you want to make **a web crawler with selenium webdriver test framework**, which doesn't really make sense. *Selenium* was meant for automating web browsers, which is generally (although not always) used for testing. You may actually want to look into something like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), which was specifically designed for screen-scraping and web crawling.

Comment: I am trying to create a web crawler with selenium webdriver test framework. All I want to do is to declare all functions in one file and call them from another file. I want to keep the interface as abstract as possible.
Yes, My indentation is correct and the above code works perfectly. Can you suggest me a way to define the open_url() function outside the scope of test_urlfunctions(). I tried it, but i keep getting Indentation errors.